# GIS Data: French Colonial Cercles

Tags: data-request, geospatial, historical, africa, france

[Cercles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercle_(French_colonial)) and districts were administrative units in French colonial Africa. I am looking for GIS data on their boundaries. Hints on where to find adequate digitizable historic maps on those administrative regions are also welcome.

Comment: Have you found it ? My suggest to you is to contact the university either in Geography or History department that they may be able to help you out...

Comment: I have not found it so far. The common geography or history department does not hold what I am looking for. However, there should be digitizable historic maps in some central archives around the world.

Comment: Are you seeking historical old maps that had the French Colonial Cercles , correct ?

Comment: I prefer GIS data of French colonial cercles. But as such data is apparently not available, I am also looking for historical maps which I could digitize.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have google around but yeah it's hard to find..

https://guides.library.upenn.edu/c.php?g=475518&p=3254771

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/free-sources-of-mapping-data-for-france

http://www.ign.fr/

My suggest you to find any universitites in France that might have these what you are looking for either in GIS data or historical scanned maps...